# Card Splitting in BlackJack

Tags: java

Anyone???? Hi, in my black jack game i implemented splits by first asking the player to double down and if he rejects then i allow him to split:

```
while(true){
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
        if(players[i].splits[j].getStatus() != true){ // splits is an array of two players hand 1 and hand 2
            System.out.print("Choose your next move, " + players[i].name + ", Hand "+ players[i].splits[j].number + ": \n" + "Points: " + players[i].splits[j].points + "\n" + "Hint: ");
            getHints(players[i].splits[j]);
            System.out.print( "\n1)Hit\n2)Stand\n");
            System.out.println();

            x2 = IO.readInt();
            if (x2==2){
                players[i].splits[j].standed = true; // if player stand...
                break;
            }else if(x2 == 1){//else deal a card
                Card c = dealCard(deck);
                updatePoints(players[i].splits[j], c);
                addCard(players[i].splits[j], c);
                System.out.println(players[i].name + ", Hand "+ players[i].splits[j].number + " was dealt:  " + c.showCardValue() + " of " + c.showCardSuit() );
                boolean isBusted = testPoints(players[i].splits, j); // test for busted
                if (isBusted == true){
                    System.out.println("BUSTED!!!!!!!!!");
                    players[i].splits[j].busted = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(players[i].name + ", Hand " + players[i].splits[j].number + " Points: "+ players[i].splits[j].points);
//                                          printStats(players[i].splits[j]);

    }
//check to end loop if split is busted to stands...
}
```

when i print the players stats i get the memory location instead of the text, can any one please help. Thank you, if you need more information please say so so i can update it.

=======

Output: 3 is the player name... 10 was the card dealt which was a split...

```
Choose your next move, 3, Hand 1: 
Points: 10
Hint: You have a 0% chance of busting
1)Hit
2)Stand

1
3, Hand 1 was dealt:  Ten of Spades
3, Hand 1 Points: 20
Choose your next move, 3, Hand 2: 
Points: 10
Hint: You have a 0% chance of busting
1)Hit
2)Stand

1
3, Hand 2 was dealt:  Five of Diamonds
3, Hand 2 Points: 15
Choose your next move, 3, Hand 1: 
Points: 20
Hint: You have a 92% chance of busting
1)Hit
2)Stand

2
3, Hand 1 Points: 20
Choose your next move, 3, Hand 2: 
Points: 15
Hint: You have a 58% chance of busting
1)Hit
2)Stand

2
3, Hand 1 : Points splitPlayer@1a758cb
Previous Cards dealt: 
Ten of Spades 

Five of Diamonds
```

splitPlayer class:

```
public class splitPlayer {

    public int points = 0;
    boolean busted = false;
    boolean standed = false;
    int number = 0;
    int ace = 0;
    String name = "";
    Card[] cardsDealt = new Card[12];


    public splitPlayer(int number, int points){
        this.number = number;
        this.name = "Hand "+ number;
        this.points = points;
    }
    public boolean getStatus(){
        if(busted == true || standed == true ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void setPoints(int points){
        this.points += points;
    }
}
```

=========

updatePoints:

```
public static void updatePoints(splitPlayer player,  Card c){

        int point = c.getValue();

        if (point == 1){


            player.ace += 1;
            player.setPoints(11);


        }else{
            player.setPoints(point);
        }

        if (player.points > 21 && player.ace > 0) {
            player.points -= 10;
            player.ace --;
        }





        return;
    }
```

Comment: What do `showCardValue()` and `showCardSuit()` return? You might want to make sure these are of type `String`, or are instances of classes that implement `toString()`.

Comment: "memory location" tells us, that you print an instance of a class that does not have an implementation of `toString()`. Hard to give more hints without knowing your classes (like: what is the return type of `players.cardsDealt[j].showCardValue()`)

Comment: Posting your exact output would help too -- so we could match up what you get with your code.

Comment: the return type is a string for sure

Comment: What is the line of code displaying this "memory allocation"?

Comment: i updated to show output

Comment: What is the type of `players.points` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `players[i].splits[j].points`

Comment: This is just impossible to read. What is the line of code outputting `2 Two, Hand 1 : Points splitPlayer@ca0b6 Previous Cards dealt:`?

Comment: The output is not coming from the code you've posted. I'd expect a new line before `Previous Cards dealt:`.

Comment: yes i dont know it didnt format correctly

Comment: You should really, really organize your code is much, much, much smaller methods. It would make your life much easier, your code much more readable, and it would help you post the relevant code instead of a bunch of irrelevant lines of code.

Comment: i tried but the thing is i try and then it breaks  my code every time sorry about that

Comment: Please isolate the single line of code and its matching line in the output, you are in a far better position than we are to do that.

Comment: I mean: what is the line of code outputting `Six, Hand 1 : Points splitPlayer@1a758cb` for example?

Comment: ok i tried is sys.out.print and updated the output and the code:

Comment: I wish we still had the homework tag

Comment: you know the problem steve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit appears to be this line of code:

```
System.out.println(players[i].name + ", Hand " + players[i].splits[j].number + " Points: "+ players[i].splits[j].points);
```

To figure out what is wrong, you need to know what the type of `players[i].splits[j].points` is. According to the output, it appears to be an instance of the `splitPlayer` class. You might be able to solve the problem by overloading the `toString()` method of this class. I can't know for sure without confirmation that the above line of code is really causing the problem. I also need to see more of your code, in particular the declaration of the `points` data member which is used here.

**Addendum:**

The reason that you see `splitPlayer@1a758cb` in the output is because you are concatenating an object with a `String`. Java will automatically call the `toString()` method of the object. If the object's class does not provide a `toString()` method, the one in `Object` will be called which gives the output you see.

Comment: @user1796681 Then you need to override the `toString()` method.

Comment: how would i do that? also is there a specific reason it doesnt work?

Comment: @user1796681 Start by googling for "method overriding in Java" or something similar (or look it up in your textbook). I have edited my answer to include an explanation about why your program gives this particular output.

Comment: but i didnt print the object i printed the int inside the object?

Comment: @user1796681 What is the declaration for the `points` variable? If it is an `int`, then the line of code which produces the output you are trying to fix is not in the code that you posted in your question. You are printing a `splitPlayer` object *somewhere* in your code.

Comment: i already added the splitPlayer class

Comment: To continue, you need to find which line of code prints `3, Hand 1 : Points splitPlayer@1a758cb`.

Comment: i believe that is the only line that prints it

Comment: if you want to check you can check in index.java here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4c9gj5hs6lwrzv9/qfKYhZxUCv

Comment: @user1796681 Debugging code is a critical skill as a programmer. If you are using an IDE, such as NetBeans or Eclipse, you should take the time to its how to use their powerful debugging tools. You can step through your code until you find which line causes the output that you want to fix.

Comment: i dont know how to debug, you have a tutorial?

Comment: @user1796681 What are you using to write your programs?

Comment: @user1796681 If you are using Eclipse, check out the help files. They will explain how to use the debugger.

Comment: @user1796681 Check the help files. They have a lot of information about debugging.